# Collectiion was modified(monogame)

Tags: monogame

I did use this...and when i changed Screens it gave me this error : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

```
foreach(var screen in ScreenList)
```

Inside Base Screen

```
  public void HideScreen()
    {
        Enabled = true;
        Visible = true;
        alpha = 0;
        fade = Fade.Out; 

    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Enabled = true;
        alpha = 1;
        fade = Fade.Out;
    }
```

And in Screen manager

```
 public static void ChangeScreen(BaseScreen CurrentScreen, BaseScreen TargetedScreen)
    {
        TargetedScreen.HideScreen();
        AddScreen(CurrentScreen);
        RemoveScreen(TargetedScreen);
        CurrentScreen.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is a general C# problem. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute - it is a better answer then you'll get here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error typically happens when you remove an item from a collection during the `foreach` loop. So to simplify what's happening in your code is something like this:

```
foreach(var screen in ScreenList)
{
    if(whatever)
        ScreenList.Remove(screen);
}
```

There's a few different ways to solve this.

The first simple way is to make a copy of the list before you enumerate it.

```
foreach(var screen in ScreenList.ToArray())
```

The downside of this approach is that the copy operation can be a performance hit if the list is large.

The second is to use a `for` loop instead.

```
for(var i = 0; i < ScreenList; i++)
{
    var screen = ScreenList[i];

    if(whatever)
    { 
        ScreenList.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that it's more complicated because you have to make sure you don't skip over one of the items. I'm not even sure I've got this one right.

The third approach is to have some way to mark the items for removal and remove them later.

```
foreach(var screen in ScreenList)
{
    if(whatever)
        screen.IsRemoved = true;
}

ScreenList.RemoveAll(i => i.IsRemoved);
```

The downside is that you have to add an extra property to your objects.

The last approach is to hold the removed items in another list temporarily and remove them later.

```
var removedList = new List<Screen>();

foreach(var screen in ScreenList)
{
    if(whatever)
        removedList.Add(screen);
}

foreach(var screen in removedList)
    ScreenList.Remove(screen);
```

The downside of this approach is the extra memory allocation of another list.

I've used all of these in various situations and I'm still not completely happy with any of them. I'll let you decide which approach is better for you.

Comment: If you want to remove items from a list in a for-loop, you best start with "i = list.count -1" and decrement i at every step, then you don't have to mess around with i in the body.

Comment: That crossed my mind but I didn't want to change the order. It occurs to me now it could work by indexing into the array differently